# Can someone help me with display my products image?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display my products image but I couldn't and I've go through all the possible solutions still doesn't work. Here is  my code.

```
<img src="/storage/2020/08/18{{ $product['image']  }}" />
```

My image directory structure is "public/storage/2020/mySampleImage.png"

Thanks for your concern

Comment: `<img src="{{ url('public/storage/2020/08/18'.$product['image']) }}"`

Comment: this didn't work.

Comment: if your directory structure is like above why dont you call it without the "08/18" ?

Comment: Make sure you also run `php artisan storage:link` to create a shortcut towards your storage directory.

Comment: I tried calling it without the "08/18" earlier doesn't work.

Comment: And I I've run the command already

Comment: Use this `<img src="{{ url('/storage/2020/' .$product['image']) }}"`

Comment: This on too don't work. Please I don't know, do I have to do something in my controller to get the image? because I didn't change my controller

Comment: Try `<img src="{{ url('/storage/2020/08/18/' .$product['image']) }}"`

Comment: Can you open the developer tools in the browser and check what the `src` is for the image?

Comment: what do you mean by dont work? Is the value of src wrong or something else.

Comment: I meant it didn't work, am sorry it was a typo.

Comment: This is what I have in the dev tools "<img src="http://e-commerce.com/storage/2020/08/18/http://localhost/storage/2020/08/18/3d80916c1f352654b142af0b1fc423bffdb68dd5.png">"

Comment: It seems that `$product['image']` returns a full url, do you have a accessor that converts `image` to a url?

Comment: If that's the case just do this `<img src="{{ $product['image']  }}" />`

Comment: No I don't have any accessor

Comment: how is `image` stored in the db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220094/discussion-between-nasir-001-and-cleancode).

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/storage/2020/08/18{ $product['image']  }" />
```

I have used like this and it work correctly in my project